# Cant send multiple files using Wifi Direct (Client Server Socket)

Tags: android, sockets, io, wifi-direct

i am developeing app using Wifi direct to send files to other device, right now i am able to send single file through this code given below but when i send multiple files on first file shares and rest don't send 
In my onConnectionInfoAvailable method i use this code

```
  @Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Connect success");
    Log.e(TAG, info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Transfer files...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    if (info.isGroupOwner) {
        Intent receiveIntent = new Intent(this, ServerService.class);
        receiveIntent.setAction(ServerService.ACTION_RECEIVE);
        this.startService(receiveIntent);
    } else {
        if (mTransferFilesTask == null) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);

            /*File file = makeDataFile("dropItFile", sendingFilesModelList.toString());*/

            new TransferFilesTask(sendingFilesModelList,
                    info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress(), "1234").execute("");




        } else mTransferFilesTask = null;
    }
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

In my AsyncTask Class

```
 @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class TransferFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

    private String mAddress;
    private String mPort;
    private List<SendingFilesModel> mFiles;
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 8000;

    TransferFilesTask(List<SendingFilesModel> files, String address, String port) {
        mFiles = files;
        mAddress = address;
        mPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            Socket socket = new Socket();

            try {

                Log.e(TAG, "Opening client socket - ");
                socket.bind(null);
                Log.e(TAG, mAddress + " port: " + mPort);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(mAddress, Integer.parseInt(mPort))), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                Log.e(TAG, "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());

                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);


                dos.writeInt(mFiles.size());
                Log.e(TAG, mFiles.size() + "");
                int added = 100 / mFiles.size();
                int status = 100 %  mFiles.size();
                for (SendingFilesModel file : mFiles) {Here SendingFilesModel is a custom object list in which i am getting files name, size and path
                    Log.e("getFilePath", file.getFilePath());

                    long wrtLong = Long.parseLong(file.getFileSize());
                    dos.writeLong(wrtLong);
                    Log.e("length Main", "length: " + file.getFileActullSize());
                    String name = file.getFileName();
                    dos.writeUTF(name);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getFilePath());
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    int theByte;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while ((theByte = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, theByte);
                        bos.flush();
                    }
                    bis.close();

                    status = status + added;
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(status);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Client: Data written");

                    dos.close();
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Client: stop service");
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            this.cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and in my ServerService class

```
public class ServerService extends IntentService {
/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
String dirPath;
private static final String TAG = ServerService.class.getName();
public static final String ACTION_RECEIVE = "action_receive";
public static final String FILES_NAME = "files_name";
private List<String> mFileName = new ArrayList<>();

public ServerService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public ServerService() {
    super("ServerService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_RECEIVE.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, action);

        String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFiles";
        File folder = new File(dirPath + "/MyFiles");
        folder.mkdirs();

        if (folder.exists()) {
            Log.e("FOLDER EXISTS", "FOLDER EXISTS");
        } else {
            Log.e("FOLDER CREATED", "FOLDER CREATED");
        }

        try {

            /**
             * Create a server socket and wait for client connections. This
             * call blocks until a connection is accepted from a client
             */
            Log.e(TAG, "server create");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(1234));
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.e(TAG, "client accept");

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            int filesCount = dis.readInt();

            File[] files = new File[filesCount];

            for (int i = 0; i <= filesCount; i++) {

                long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                String fileName = dis.readUTF();

                Log.e(TAG, "name: " + fileName);
                Log.e(TAG, "length: " + fileLength);

                files[i] = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);

                int theByte;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (fileLength > 0 && (theByte = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, fileLength))) != -1) {

                    fos.write(buffer, 0, theByte);
                    fileLength -= theByte;
                }

                fos.close();
                Log.e(TAG, "get file: " + fileName);
                mFileName.add(fileName);
                //bos.close();
                //new MediaScannerWrapper(getApplicationContext(), dirPath + "/" + fileName, "music/*").scan();
            }

            dis.close();

            serverSocket.close();

            Log.e(TAG, "saved file and close server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage() + "");

        }
        Intent transferDoneIntent = new Intent();
        transferDoneIntent.setAction(MainReceiver.ACTION_TRANSFER_DONE);
        //transferDoneIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(FILES_NAME, (ArrayList<String>) mFileName);
        sendBroadcast(transferDoneIntent);
        stopSelf();

    }
}

private class MediaScannerWrapper implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
    private String mPath;
    private String mMimeType;

    public MediaScannerWrapper(Context context, String filePath, String mime) {
        mPath = filePath;
        mMimeType = mime;
        mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    }

    public void scan() {
        mConnection.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

}
After sending first file in serverservice class this code gives me IOException

```
com.example.youxian.wifidirecttransfer E/IOException: malformed input around byte 0
```

where i am making mistake? either i am not sending right Object list to FileInputStream or not making call to server to receive file. i dont know please help....